# Python / Using os.path.getsize to discriminate a list

Tags: python

I use this code to print the filesize of my directory

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, getsize    

pdf_files = [f for f in listdir(folder_location) if isfile(join(folder_location, f)) & f.lower().endswith(".pdf")] 

for index, f2 in enumerate(pdf_files):
      print(index, f2, getsize(folder_location+f2))
```

The result is :

```
1 1-01-01-3.pdf 1191722
2 1-01-01-4.pdf 885649
3 1-01-01-5.pdf 254760
4 1-01-01-6.pdf 1425127
5 1-01-01-8.pdf 1456785
6 1-02-01-1.pdf 264252
7 1-02-01-2.pdf 1769278
```

(in Windows it makes 1164 Ko, 865 Ko, 249 Ko...)

So let's say I want to select only the file with a size superior to 18Ko
When I use the following syntax, I have no result in my list

```
pdf_files = [f for f in listdir(folder_location) if isfile(join(folder_location, f)) & f.lower().endswith(".pdf") & getsize(folder_location+f)>18000 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `and` for boolean logic, not `&`.

But the problem is here: `getsize(folder_location+f)`

This way the separator is missing, use `getsize(join(folder_location, f))`

Comment: The failure to use `join` isn't actually causing the problem in the OP's code; if it was, they'd be getting `FileNotFoundError`s. They omitted the definition of `folder_location`, but since they're not getting exceptions, you know that `folder_location` already included a trailing slash. Using `join` doesn't hurt, and will help if `folder_location` ever omits the trailing slash, but it's not what's solving their problem, and you shouldn't say it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that `&` has higher precedence than `and`. As a result, when you do:

```
 isfile(join(folder_location, f)) & f.lower().endswith(".pdf") & getsize(folder_location+f)>18000
```

it executes *everything* left of the `>` as a value, computing the bitwise-and of `isfile`, `endswith(".pdf")` and `getsize`. Since the former two only return `True` or `False`, the result of said bitwise-and will *always* be `0` or `1`, both of which are less than 18000, so nothing passes your test.

You have a secondary issue, where if `folder_location` didn't already end with trailing slash, you'd get `FileNotFoundError`s on your `getsize` calls; you clearly have such a trailing slash, so it's not hurting this code, but if `folder_size` ever lacks one you'd want it, so use `os.path.join` consistently, like you did for `is_file`.

While parentheses could be used to fix the bitwise-and vs. `>` precedence issue so it logically works (all your tests do return `True`/`False`, you're not relying on "truthiness" testing where one of the tests might produce `10` and break a bitwise-and test), making it `... f.lower().endswith(".pdf") & (getsize(join(folder_location, f))>18000)]` (note parens around `getsize > 18000` and using `join` as in your `isfile` test to ensure proper directory separators), in practice, you want to use boolean operators (`not`, `and`, `or`), not bitwise ones (`~`, `&`, `|`); they work even if the results aren't strictly `0`/`1`/`False`/`True`, and they short-circuit; your cheap filename test, when it fails, can avoid a costly `stat` system call to check the size. To fix and optimize this, you want:

```
pdf_files = [f for f in listdir(folder_location)
             if f.lower().endswith(".pdf") and isfile(join(folder_location, f)) and
                getsize(join(folder_location, f)) > 18000]
```

which performs the (effectively free relative to the other tests) file name check first to minimize `stat` calls by using `and` to short-circuit when any test fails.

That said, this is a *perfect* case for replacing `os.listdir` (which only returns file names, eagerly, and thus requires rejoining them to the directory and repeatedly `stat`ing said files for each test) [with `os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) (which returns file data lazily, operating much more efficiently on large folders, and returns `DirEntry` objects that cheaply get you both the name and the qualified path, gives some file information for free without `stat`ing, especially on Windows where *all* the info is free, and for the non-free things on non-Windows, it caches a single `stat` call, which would reduce the work in your code from 1-3 `stat` calls per file to 0-1):

```
from os import scandir  # scandir removes the need for any os.path imports at all

# This listcomp performs at most one stat system call per file on non-Windows,
# and only if the entry is a file and the name ends in .pdf, while
# on Windows it never performs a single stat call, ever
pdf_files = [e for e in scandir(folder_location)
             if e.name.lower().endswith(".pdf") and e.is_file() and
                e.stat().st_size > 18000] 

# Every entry in pdf_files that needed to be stat-ed cached the results,
# so this loop involves no stats, on any OS; .stat() cached the result on the first call
for index, e in enumerate(pdf_files):
      print(index, e.name, e.stat().st_size)
```

This will be *dramatically* faster on large directories, especially if said directories are NFS-mounted or any are on any other slow storage medium.